# It is posible to build a Progressive Web App (PWA) taking a user as a subdomain?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I'm diving in the world of the PWA and I was wondering if is possible to configure the manifest.json and the service workers in some way to generate a start URL with the user subdomain.

I have read that is possible to Build PWA on multi-subdomain sites, for example, site sections: www.site.com, listing.site.com or product.site.com.

https://medium.com/@drenzulli/building-progressive-web-apps-on-multi-subdomain-sites-fbd3384d0706

In my case, I don't have a specific URL because the user will create it and will be a subdomain. Example: a new user (testuser) register on my app, so his subdomain will be: testuser.site.com

So the manifest.json should be something like this:

```
{
  "name": "the app name",
  "short_name": "app",
  "description": "cool app",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "theme_color": "#fff",
  "categories": ["lifestyle"],
  "start_url": "https://testuser.site.com",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/public/images/logo-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

So, it is possible to generate with logic or some else the start_url depending on the username of the user?

Comment: Hey, Did you solve this issue ?